# Generic Questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Are generic questions like: [How do I write a While loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395/how-do-i-write-a-while-loop) still on-topic?

If these questions are encountered should they be voted to close (to broad? un-clear what you are asking? lacking an understanding of the problem to be solved?) or ignored?

If the intent was to be a resource for new programmers, it has failed (1k views in 5years).

Comment: I think if a similar question was asked today, it would probably be downvoted to oblivion and perhaps quickly closed. It's a programming question, but it's also asking for a list of things, and that type of question rarely works with the Q&A format of the site.

Comment: @Yannis So what should I do about it now?

Comment: You can vote to close it, but it's a question that was last active 4 years ago, you can also just... forget about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Overflow is not good at teaching people how to program from scratch, and that's basically what that question is.  Nowadays, we require people to demonstrate a minimal level of knowlege, and if you can't write a while loop, well...

I closed the question.

Comment: Plus, the question is rather broad, supposing that "How do you write the syntax for a While loop?" means "What is the syntax of a While loop?" I cannot imagine how helpful is to have a single question showing the syntax used by all the programming languages for that control statement.

Answer (score -1):

It is a question about programming, so yes it is.

It's debatable about whether you want to ask specific questions like that though because invariably the new question will be a duplicate - unless you can come up with an angle on it that no-one has before.

You also need to be cautious about asking the question in a way that is likely to produce extended discussion (which is not encouraged) - the example question you've used is not particularly clear - is it a list question, or asking about a grammar?